# MS Word checkbox control not checkable when saved as PDF

Tags: pdf, ms-word

I have a MS Word document that implements a form people can fill in. It is mostly just table cells that represent text fields people can type in and checkbox controls that allow them to check the box to select an option. I then save the document as a PDF document.

When I test the PDF form by selecting the "fill and sign" option, I've found that some checkboxes are "checkable", but others are not. They were all added to the form the same way, so I'm at a loss as to why some work and others do not.

I've looked at the properties of the control, but am not seeing anything different from a working checkbox vs a non-working checkbox.

Has anyone run into this? Any ideas on what could be wrong? Is there a MS forum that might be a better place for this question?

Comment: Exporting a Word-document as pdf won't create fillable pdf. Are you using Acrobat inbetween - or how do you get a fillable pdf form?

Comment: All I did was save the Word document as PDF. If I open the PDF and select to "fill and sign", when the mouse is moved over checkboxes, the cursor changes to a checkbox and if you click it, selects/deselects the checkbox. If you move over any table cell, it highlights the cell. You can click it and enter text. The weird thing is that some of the checkboxes behave this way, but others do not.

Comment: Which pdf-viewer are you using? Foxit? I think it depends more on what Foxit is "interpreting" based on the created pdf - e.g. recognizing a small square as a check box etc. And propably some squares are more accurate than others ....

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Reader.